# terraform apply pass variable to deploy specific ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I have a number of ECS. Is it possible to pass a variable to ecs-container-definition.json to deploy to a specific ECS?

e.g. terraform apply -var 'deploy=aws-ecs-backend'

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have any code to show demonstrating what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there are a few overlapping concepts here. You don't specify what version of Terraform you are using so I'll assume it's relatively recent.

The Terraform resource you are likely referring to is an [ecs_task_definition](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition). This resource takes the following format (from the docs):

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "service" {   
    family = "service"
    container_definitions = jsonencode([

     //ommitted for brevity

    ])

}
```

It appears you are instead using the [file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/file.html) or [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) functions to embed the contents of a file called *ecs-container-definition.json* into your resource. From Terraform's perspective, you do not apply changes to this file, you apply changes to the resource referring to it (the *aws_ecs_task_definition*).

The process you are trying to undertake is [resource targeting](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/resource-targeting), and it is invoked (for example) by specifying the target resource in the `terraform apply` command. Here is an example, if your **ecs_task_definition** resource is called **myservice** you will have the below:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "myservice" {   
    family = "service"
    container_definitions = file('./templates/aws_ecs_task_definition')
    .....
}
```

You would then apply changes to this resource using the below command (run from the same directory as the containing .tf file:

`terraform plan -target="aws_ecs_task_definition.myservice"` (to see planned changes)

`terraform apply -target="aws_ecs_task_definition.myservice"` (to apply changes)

Be aware that this is something of a Terraform anti-pattern, as the documentation states [in the opening paragraph](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/resource-targeting):

> Occasionally you may want to only apply part of a plan, such as
> situations where Terraform's state has become out of sync with your
> resources due to a network failure, a problem with the upstream cloud
> platform, or a bug in Terraform or its providers.

Generally best practice is to have Terraform "cleanly apply" in that all of the state is in sync with your repository content.